# Custom UITableViewCell init

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have created a custom `UITableViewCell` using storyboards.

I am loading it like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    HJAddCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"addCell"];
    // setting properties of cell 
    return cell;
}
```

Now I need to add some more customization programmatically during initialization. But the problem is that in my `HJAddCell`, the `init` methods are not called. What should I do so that the the `init` method is called or is there any other way to add more customization code to the custom cell class at init time with minimum effort.

Update: I need to add borders to UILabels. I didn't find any thing to do this in storyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course the init methods are not being called. You are not calling any init methods yourself. If you are registering HJAddCell's nib with the table view, the initialization method being called is initWithCoder. If you are using a nib, you should also ask yourself about why do you need to customize a custom UITableViewCell on the runtime. I mean, it's already a custom cell. You should create the cell with the properties you need to have.

Comment: I am not using any Nibs. I have created the Cell in storyboards. Sorry if I'm mistaken in understanding difference b/w nibs and storyboards

Comment: You can customize your table view cell under a storyboard. You can add as many view elements as you want. You should not need to do customization on the runtime.

Comment: To be more precise I need to add to border to a UILabel. I didn't find any thing to do this in storyboard. :/

Comment: subclass - (void)awakeFromNib on your tableviewcell subclass and do it there.

Comment: - (void)awakeFromNib worked. I also tried in initWithCoder but the code wasn't making any effect. I guess its because the properties were not initialized at that time. Thanks! :)

Comment: I needed to change the fonts of my labels and I could set these in -(void)awakeFromNib

Answer (score 13):

UIViews have two [designated initializers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html): `initWithFrame:` and `initWithCoder:`. `initWithCoder:` is used if view is loaded from nib/storyboard, `initWithFrame` - if view is created programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a new method to HJAddCell called reset? Move the initialization code that needs to happen before each use into the reset method and call reset from your initializer.

Then you would call the reset method after dequeue-ing your cell.